# YouTube IFrame API - Untrusted Origin: Null

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

Not sure if this is a bug in the API or a security feature in Chrome but when trying to run the YT IFrame API on a local file (via the File:// protocol) I get the error `Untrusted origin: null`.

The video loads but `postMessage` doesn't work so I can't run any api methods nor use events from YouTube.

Could anyone shed some light on this please?

Thanks,
Dean

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Youtube iFrame API seems to load, but never calls my "onReady" listener. Console is also full of "Untrusted Origin: Null". This is irregardless of Chrome Cast extension being installed or not, activated or not.